# Detect if user is logged in as a Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way (Server side or Client Side) if a user is logged in as a Page (Account Settings -> Use Facebook as page)?

I would like to prompt the user to switch back to themselves in my tab app if they view the app as a page.

I have tried showing the auth dialog, but that just shows an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logged in as a page you get an error when subscribing to the `auth.statusChange` event so it will not fire. So I wait for 3 seconds to see if the event fired and if not redirect to the auth dialog page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isUser = false;
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) { isUser = true; });

    setTimeout(function() { if (!isUser) { window.top.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<YOUR APP ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIR URL>'; } }, 3000);
</script>
```

This works, but seems like a HORRIBLE hack.

Comment: It seems that statusChange now does fire when using as page.